Проблемы с Bevel в Blender
После создания новых вершин у куба при помощи Ctrl+R и задания ему необходимой формы, параметр Bevel стал полностью неработоспособен, фаска не появляется. Отображение модификаторов включено.
Как решить проблему?
P.S. - Сочетание Ctrl+B работает, но я хочу именно чтобы была КРУГЛАЯ фаска, а Bevel, нужный для этого, не работает.
